# How do I use Pólya's enumeration theorem to solve this toy-swapping problem?

Tags: combinatorics, polya-counting-theory

Say we have $n$ children sitting in a ring. Each child is given an arbitrary toy that is either red or blue. We know that children, being as they are, can be somewhat fickle and very sociable, so if a child does not like their toy, they swap toys with their immediate neighbor. Neighbors will only trade toys once. They can swap toys of the same color (a red firetruck for a red yo-yo, for example), or toys of different colors. After the trades are done, we then go back around the circle and check the colors of each toy. We finally say that two colorings of the graph $C_n$ are isomorphic if one can be achieved after exactly $k$ trades. For example, in the diagram below, the three colorings in the green box are all isomorphic to the leftmost graph with $k=1$, while the one outside the box is not.

[image: There are four copies of the cyclic graph of order 4. Each graph has three blue vertices and one red vertex. The three in the green box have their red vertex in the top left, top right, and bottom left, respectively. The one outside the box has its red vertex in the bottom right.]

The question then arises: for $n$ children and $k$ swaps, how many unique distributions of toy colors are there? My first instinct was to try using PET to solve this, but I quickly ran into an issue; the theorem only works with groups, and the set of permutations here is not a group. For example, again, with $k=1$ and $n=4$, the permutations $(12)$ and $(34)$ are both members of the set, but $(12)(34)$ is not. It is not a closed set.

My next instinct was to use PET on each individual permutation and then add them up. For example, I thought we could say $G=\{I,(12)\}$, and then $Z(G)=\frac{1}{2}(a_4+a_1^2a_2)$, and then rinse and repeat for our other permutations. However, again, we run into a problem. With this method, multiple versions of the same graph get counted as "unique" graphs. This method is a no-go as well.

How can I approach this problem? I feel like PET or Burnside's lemma should be applicable here to sort out all the duplicated, but I can't for the life of me figure out how.

Comment: I'm not sure unique distributions is a well-defined concept. What are the unique distributions in your example with n=4, k=1 and with 1 red toy?  The two distributions with the red toy at child 1 or 3? Or at child 2 or 4? It gets worse with for example, n=6, k=1, and 1 red toy. Are there three unique distributions (red toy starts at 1, 3 or 5) or just two (red toy starts at 1 or 4)? The problem is that being k swaps apart is not an equivalence relation (it is non-transitive) so the arrangements don't split into neat well-defined sets.

Comment: Would it be possible to turn each graph coloring into a word and then give preference to the lexicographically earliest graph as the "canonical" graph? For example, all the graphs with three blue and one red could be 1000, 0100, 0010, and 0001, and then we say that 0001 and 0100 are our two unique graphs from this configuration. Or does this idea not have legs?